# Postgres.exe crashes and tears down all apps, recovers and is running again

Tags: postgresql

I'm running an application with about 20 processes connected to a postgres DB (10.0) on windows server 2016.

Since about a month I have unexpected crashes of postgres.exe.
To isolate the problem I extended the logging by setting log_min_duration_statement = 0

This creates more detailed logfile. What I can see is:

```
LOG:  server process (PID xxxxx) was terminated by exception
0xFFFFFFFF DETAIL:  Failed process was running: COMMIT HINT:  See C
include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
```

Then it tears down all 20 processes like this:

```
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.Then DB recovers:
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-06-11 18:17:18 CEST
```

DB enters recovery mode

```
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
...
LOG:  redo starts at 1B2/33319E58
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
LOG:  invalid record length at 1B2/33D29930: wanted 24, got 0
LOG:  redo done at 1B2/33D29908
LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2021-06-11 18:21:39.830526+02
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
...
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Now it's running again like normal

The crashed PID xxxxx I can identify to a postgres.exe running for one of the 20 application processes. It's not always the same one. This happens about every 5-10 days.

Can anybody give me some advice how to track down the reason of this crash?

Extensions used:

```
oracle_fdw 2.0.0, PostgreSQL 10.0, Oracle client 11.2.0.3.0, Oracle server 11.2.0.2.0
```

Crashdump:

Followed the link :
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Windows

Although the postgres user has "full control" of the crashdump folder in the security tab it does not write something. Folder stays empty.

Follow-Up on the comment @Laurenz Albe:
The COMMIT is not the reason of the crash. It is the last successfull executed command of the session. Explained on the following example:

Process gets a job and starts to do it's job

```
2021-06-15 16:27:51.100 CEST [25604] LOG:  duration: 0.061 ms  statement: DISCARD ALL
2021-06-15 16:27:51.100 CEST [25604] LOG:  duration: 0.012 ms  statement: BEGIN
2021-06-15 16:27:51.100 CEST [25604] LOG:  duration: 0.015 ms  statement: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

now a lot of action going on within session 25604
and among others the oracle foreign datawrapper

```
2021-06-15 16:28:13.792 CEST [25604] LOG:  duration: 0.016 ms  execute <unnamed>: FETCH ALL FROM "<unnamed portal 689>"
```

finishes action successfully (data of the transaction in the database)

```
2021-06-15 16:28:13.823 CEST [25604] LOG:  duration: 0.059 ms  statement: COMMIT
```

a lot of action is going in different sessions
among others the oracle foreign datawrapper

more the 7 minutes afterwards the next job is requested and now postgres.exe crash

```
2021-06-15 16:36:01.524 CEST [17904] LOG:  server process (PID 25604) was terminated by exception 0xFFFFFFFF
```

The process does not do DISCARD ALL, BEGIN and SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
It crashes immediately

My Conclusion:
"the possibly corrupted shared memory" was initiated by one of the processes before. Meaning between the last successful COMMIT and the new request.
That's a 7 minutes time span where the problem occurs.

Some feedback on this conclusion?

Comment: If a `COMMIT` is crashing, that is bad. What extensions are installed?

Comment: Maybe it is an already fixed bug.  The current minor release of 10 is 10.17.  Don't run software with nearly 4 years of unfixed known bugs.

Comment: Is there an Anti-Virus program running? If yes, disable it - at least for Postgres' data directory

Comment: @jjanes: I didnt find some info in the postgres docs.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I found this in posgres docs too: There is no virus scanner running

Comment: Please [edit]  the question and add the information there. PostgreSQL is crashing *during* the commit: `Failed process was running: COMMIT`. Was there a query on a foreign table involved in the transaction? It would be great to get a stack trace from the crash (difficult on Windows).